# Update panel issue in visual web part

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, updatepanel

I have created a web part using update panel and the page where I placed that web part there is also a task list with timeline view.

My problem is that whenever my update panel gets posted back the task list's div gets repeated. But when I refresh the page it gets normal.

To get clear idea refer following steps.

1. [Normal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgEIV.png)
2. [State after clicking edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GICDf.png)
3. [State after cancel button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG9Iu.png)
4. [State after refreshing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIXZ6.png)

My declarative part is [here](http://paste.org/68977).

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it working, if you change the view of tasks list on the page?

Comment: The same issue occurs with different view also.

Comment: Seems to be very weird issue. Facing the same issue on my machine as well. Well I would suggest of removing the update panel for now and do a Postback :P

Comment: Yes this work around would work well in the worst case, but it's not optimum. Thanks for entertaining the issue :(